# Finding last row containing data with Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm reading from an excel file and printing to console (for now). The problem is the excel file I'm reading from is being edited by several people and they have the table extended down hundreds of rows for convenience as it's updated 15ish times a day and Apache POI considers this as data and ends up printing hundreds of lines of nothing as a result. My code below. I thought the if current.Row.iterator() == null would end the while loop?

```
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Row currentRow = iterator.next();
        Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = currentRow.iterator();

        if (currentRow.iterator() == null) { // i thought this would exit the while loop?
            return;
        }
        while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
            Cell currentCell = cellIterator.next();

            if (currentCell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.STRING) { // todo: probably don't need the if/else if?
                System.out.print(currentCell.getStringCellValue() + "  ");
            } else if (currentCell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.NUMERIC) {
                String currentCellAsString = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(currentCell);
                System.out.print(currentCellAsString + "  ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: I *suppose* an iterator would never return null and you have to rely on the outer `iterator.hasNext`

Comment: You should correct your first while loop itself to take `Row currentRow = iterator.next();`

Comment: @N00bPr0grammer I'm sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: Did you try [reading and following the Apache POI documentation on iterating over rows and cells](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator)?

Comment: Yes, I've tried for (Row row : sheet) {if (row == null); return;} but this ends the program before it prints anything